# try / except python handling and int() function

Tags: python, int, try-catch

Fairly new to the Pythonic Way, but the below code doesn't work as expected, anyone know why?
If I input 143.22 I get "not an int" response, rather than the expected collatz(143) e.g., int(143.22). BTW, this is one basic exercise in the *Automate the Boring Stuff with Python* beginners book (chapter 3 exercise on using functions). Thanks!

```
def collatz(myint) :
    print(myint)   
    if myint % 2 == 0 :
        myint = int(myint / 2)
    else:
        myint = int(myint *3 +1)
    if myint == 1 :
        print(myint)
        return myint
    else:
        collatz(myint)

try:
    x=input('Input a non-negative integer between 1 and infinity: ')
    val = int(x)
    if int(x) == abs(int(x)) :
        print("Yes input string is an Integer.")
        collatz(val)
    else:
        print('I did say NON negative!')
except ValueError:
    print("That's not a positive int!")
```

Comment: Indeed 143.22 isn't a positive int, it is a float. Do you want your program to handle both floats (by rounding?) and ints?

Comment: the error is caused from `val = int(x)`. You can apply `int(143.22)`, but you are not allowed to `int('143.22')`. Read more https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#int

Comment: Also, you can replace `int(x) == abs(int(x))` by `val == abs(val)`.

Comment: It seems to me like your program is working fine. You are asking for a non-negative integer, and when giving it 143.22 it shouts "that's not an int". What seems to be the problem?

Comment: I believe @facehugger has it nailed; removing that (val=int(x)) line makes no difference in the functioning of the routine, so I consider this a learning exercise in type conversion/casting as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to run int('143.22')

For me, this yields:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    int('143.22')
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '143.22'
```

However, int(143.22) works fine.

A quick solution for your use case may be to cast it as a float.

```
float('143.22')

int(float('143.22'))
```

Comment: Thanks! Python appears to be somewhere a 'strongly typed' and 'loosely typed' language, my background with both Perl and C# seems to make the learning curve a bit longer, but ... *worth the journey*!!